# Which database normalisation tools can i use?

Tags: mysql, database, normalization, database-normalization

I have legacy database with out FK.
I would like to link all tables with help of some program.
[Database schema example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mxIlA.png)

Comment: wonderfully descriptive schema object names, too. Good luck.

Comment: FK constraints are used to enforce data integrity, they don't "link" tables or records and they're not required to join.

Answer (score 0):

Database normalization requires analysis skills, understanding database content and understanding it's relationship, it's working domain.

You are unlikely find a piece of software that will automatically normalize a database.

***It's like asking for harry's wand***

Comment: At this example i had many same fields at different tables. For this reason i want program for transform this db to 1NF.